# Prove that an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is diagonalisable and invertible if and only if $A=I_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Through some facts, when $A$ is invertible, I found out that the eigenvalue can't be $0$, since if the eigenvalue is $0$, then $\det(A)=0$, which means that is is not invertible. Since it is over $\mathbb{Z}_2$, then eigenvalue is $1$.

Since the eigenvalue $(\lambda)$ is $1$, and $Av = \lambda v$, then $Av = v$ when $A=I$.

However, I didn't quite get how it can be diagonalizable if and only if $A=I$, or did I get it wrong somewhere? please help :)

Comment: You've already shown that if it's diagonalizable and invertible, then it's *conjugate* to $I$—do you see this? Do you see how to finish the problem from there?

Comment: How do you get that the eigenvalue must be $1$?  For example $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ is invertible, but doesn't have $0$ or $1$ as eigenvalue.  The eigenvalue is in some extension of $\mathbb{F}_2$.  (The eigenvalues are $1$, but the logic is insufficient.)  How does being diagonalizable help?

Comment: I think he meant diagonalizable over $\mathbb{F}_2$, not over a field extension of $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: @Batominovski I agree, but it could also be that the OP believes that if $M\in M_n(k)$ then the eigenvalues of $M$ are in $k$.  (Which is not true if $k$ is not algebraically closed).

Comment: I thought that the eigenvalue couldn't be 0, since if the eigenvalue is 0, then the det(A-$\lambda$) = det(A), which means that det(A)=0 and therefore is not invertible am I doing it wrong somewhere here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is diagonalizable with eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n$ (counted with multiplicities) then $\det(A) = \prod_{i=1}^n \lambda_i$.
If in addition $A$ is invertible then all the eigenvalues (which are in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ must be equal to one which implies that $A = I$ (since if $v_1, \dots, v_n$ are the eigenvectors and $v = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i v_i$ is a general vector, then $Av = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i Av_i = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i v_i = v$).

Answer (score 0):

Since $0$ and $1$ are the only scalars available, and a diagonal entry$~0$ in a diagonal matrix makes it singular (for instance because there is then a zero column), the only invertible diagonal matrix is the identity matrices$~I_n$. A diagonalisable matrix is by definition similar to some diagonal matrix, and invertibility is unchanged under similarity. Hence an invertible matrix over $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ that is diagonalisable (over that field) is similar to$~I_n$, but only the identity matrix itself is similar to$~I_n$.